# Create directory document that outputs file name + file path in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a full directory in python that outputs the file type and file path. I figured out a system that works. If its a file, the code prints out the file name and the path to get to it. If its not a file, it adds the name of the folder to the path and repeats the process. The problem is I had to hard-code (sorry) the paths, because I couldn't find another way to get the code to keep digging through folders until it has all of the files. Here's the code I've worked out so far which works but its super inefficient (especially if there are more folders nested than I've accounted for):

```
with os.scandir(pathi) as entries:
for entry in entries:
    if entry.is_file(): 
        print(f"File Name:{entry.name} located in {pathi}", file=f2)    
    # If entry is not a file, entry is added to path, the process is repeated 
    # until all files are recorded with their respective paths
    else: 
        path1 = f"{pathi}/{entry.name}"
        with os.scandir(path1) as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                if entry.is_file(): 
                    print(f"File Name:{entry.name} located in {path1}", file=f2)
                else: 
                    path2 = f"{path1}/{entry.name}"
                    with os.scandir(path2) as entries:
                        for entry in entries:
                            if entry.is_file(): 
                                print(f"File Name:{entry.name} located in {path2}", file=f2)
                            else: 
                                path3 = f"{path2}/{entry.name}"
                                with os.scandir(path3) as entries:
                                    for entry in entries:
                                        if entry.is_file(): 
                                            print(f"File Name:{entry.name} located in {path3}", file=f2)
```

My output is:
File Name:my_module.py located in /Users/name/DropBox/Project/Other Test

File Name:Test.docx located in /Users/name/DropBox/Project/Other Test/XXX/Path 3 test

I've tried using a while loop at the beginning of the script:

```
with os.scandir(pathi) as entries:
for entry in entries:
    while entry is entry.is_file():
        if entry.is_file(): 
            print(f"File Name:{entry.name} located in {pathi}", file=f)
        else: 
        path1 = f"{pathi}/{entry.name}"
```

But this creates an infinite loop. I've also explored using `os.walk()` and `os.path.abspath()` but neither have yielded the same results as my hard-code (sorry) above. I'm new to python and am having trouble with the way conditional loops work and didn't know if there was a way to keep my current code but have a loop that will add to the path when needed. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)?

```
import os

top = '.'

for root, _, files in os.walk(top):
    for n in files:
        print(f"File Name:{n} located in {root}")
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain a little bit what that code is doing? Additionally,  how can I specify the folder I want it to go into initially? For example, I'm only interested in the files in the DropBox folder on my desktop. I initialized a path of '/Users/name/Drop Box' and then I want to get all the files nested in other folders within that.

Comment: "how can I specify the folder I want it to go into initially?" -- you set it in the `top = ''.` line, of course